Are there drawbacks to `import type` or to enabling the `@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-imports` eslint rule?
I recently ran into an issue that was fixed by using the import type TypeScript feature instead of just import, and then discovered there's a @typescript-eslint/consistent-type-imports eslint rule which, when enabled, makes eslint --fix automatically replace import with import type where appropriate.
It seems to me that using import type instead of just import where possible is a no-brainer: It apparently allows for some optimizations during compilation, and in some cases makes code clearer to read, and it doesn't seem like it would break any existing code if used properly. Essentially, it seems useful with no drawbacks.
I've noticed, though, that the @typescript-eslint/consistent-type-imports rule is not enabled by popular eslint recommmended rulesets like airbnb-typescript or @typescript-eslint/recommended. The fact that the rule isn't recommended by these projects make me wonder if it's not as much of a free lunch as it looks.
So, are there any risks to enabling the @typescript-eslint/consistent-type-imports rule in a project?

I use that rule on a large monorepo and it's great. The eslint rule is smart enough to know when you are using it as a value, or just a type and auto-fixes your imports to match.
I can't speak to why those projects you mention don't include that rule, but I can say that I've been using that rule for a year or two and have encountered no downsides.
